# Why would my mac running slow after I installed Mactex distribution

Tags: mac

I have this question that puzzled me. My mac become quite slow after I installed MacTex distribution and after I uninstalled MacTex, it restored to the original status, running smoothly. I have to use Latex for editing, so I install the smaller basic Tex, but the dragging issue shows up again. I just wonder if this problem bothering you guys, and if there's anything I could do.

I bought this computer 5 months ago, here's the detail, MacBook Pro OS X 10.10.1(Retina, 13-inch) Processor:2.6 GHz Intel Core i5, Memory: 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3, Storage: 222GB free out of 249.77GB

Thank a lot for help.

Comment: I don't see any reason why having MacTeX installed would slow down the computer as TeX is only run while typesetting. The only thing I can think of is the editor that you are using to edit you LaTeX is causing the slowdown.

Comment: One thing I can think of is that spotlight will wish to index the files you have installed.  There are many of these, so it could take some time, but it is only done once, so should not be a permanent problem.

Comment: It's wired right? I used to use Texshop for editing, and now switch to Texpad. I have no idea what's going on, because others seem to be just fine. sigh...

Comment: What's wired? (Or is that an editor?) Are you saying that the problem is editor specific ('the others'='most editors')? Or are you saying that other people don't seem to have the issue but that you do whichever editor you try?